# I cannot go through an array and change the value in the map

Tags: lua

I have a map and an array in Lua. I don't know what the map is exactly called. Map as in C ++
And I have to go through the array and change the second argument of the Buliian one in the map. I do so. but gives an error - attempt to call a table value

```
self.arrayObjectHint = {}
self.arrayObjectHint['dustpan'] = false
self.arrayObjectHint['goblet'] = true
self.arrayObjectHint['dryflowers'] = true
self.notHint = {'goblet', 'dryflowers', 'dustpan'}
..........
for index, objectId in(self.notHint) do
  self.arrayObjectHint[objectId] = not self.arrayObjectHint[objectId]
end
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for index, objectId in(self.notHint) do
  self.arrayObjectHint[objectId] = not self.arrayObjectHint[objectId]
end
```

You forgot the iterator function in your generic for loop.

```
for index, objectId in ipairs(self.notHint) do
  self.arrayObjectHint[objectId] = not self.arrayObjectHint[objectId]
end
```